# What are these lentil like eggs? (Utah, United States)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I've found these (what appear to be eggs) attached to an apple tree in central Utah USA.

[image: Image of unidentified eggs on a tree branch]

The eggs are less than 1/2cm in length, have a waxy appearance and are attached to the branch at one end. Visually and tactilely they are quite similar to lentils.

I thought they were Box Elder bug eggs, but after a google image search I am convinced that is not what they are. What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look just like katydid eggs.

Image for comparison from the [Missouri Botanical Garden](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/insects/katydids.aspx):
[image]

Comment: Hi again. It is great that you were able to come up with an id, but you are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images (answers that are essentially just links are not sufficient). Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please also take the [tour] and consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 